# Memory usage issue when training the ML model after every specific interval

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory-management, apscheduler

I am trying to run ML training script at every 1 hour interval, but after every hour the memory usage increases by roughly 20% and after 3-4 hours, memory usage reaches to 90% and then this script throws **Memory Error**.
I am wondering why memory is not released when the train function finishes.

Although this behaviour is not shown if i run train function manually (By not using any kind of thread scheduler and calling train function twice or thrice one after another).

Any suggestion to train the model after every specific interval.

Here is the code.

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def train():

    client = MongoClient(databaseURI)
    db = client['mydb']

    movie_data = []
    for index, obj in enumerate(db.movies.find({})):
        movie_obj = {}

        movie_obj['_id'] = obj['_id']
        movie_obj['title'] = obj['title']
        movie_obj['rating'] = obj['rating']
        movie_data.append(movie_obj)


    user_data = []
    for index, obj in enumerate(db.users.find({})):
        user_obj = {}

        user_obj['_id'] = obj['_id']
        user_obj['username'] = obj['username']
        user_obj['movie_id'] = obj['movie_id']
        user_obj['rating'] = obj['rating']
        user_data.append(user_obj)


    movie_data_df = pd.DataFrame(movie_data)
    user_data_df = pd.DataFrame(user_data)

    # some ML training ALGO
    trainedModel = algo.train(user_data_df, movie_data_df)

    trained.to_pickle('files/trained.pkl')


scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(train, 'interval', hours=1, next_run_time=datetime.datetime.now())
scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Job stores house the scheduled jobs. **The default job store simply
>   keeps the jobs in memory**, but others store them in various kinds of
>   databases. A job’s data is serialized when it is saved to a persistent
>   job store, and deserialized when it’s loaded back from it. Job stores
>   (**other than the default one**) don’t keep the job data in memory, but
>   act as middlemen for saving, loading, updating and searching jobs in
>   the backend.

I suggest try one of the following solutions:

1. Change `jobstore` from the default (i.e. memory) to some persistent place ([Example](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#configuring-the-scheduler)).
2. Or try to set the parameter `replace_existing` to `True` (*as the default is `False`*).

   ```
   scheduler.add_job(train, 'interval', hours=1, 
                     next_run_time=datetime.datetime.now(), replace_existing=True)
   ```

Side-note:

I think there could be another *ugly* way to fix it (I haven't tried it!), such that you add a `Listener` to listen to the crashes and restart the whole process! (if you can try it and amend it in a more pythonic way!)

```
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(train, 'interval', hours=1, next_run_time=datetime.datetime.now())

def my_listener(event):
    if event.exception:       
        global scheduler
        scheduler.shutdown()
        gc.collect()
        scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
        scheduler.add_job(train, 'interval', hours=1, next_run_time=datetime.datetime.now())
        scheduler.add_listener(my_listener, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED | EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
        scheduler.start()

scheduler.add_listener(my_listener, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED | EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
scheduler.start()
```